# How can hide autogenerated files by TypeScript in NerdTree?

Tags: vim, typescript, nerdtree

I want to hide the auto generated files (.js .js.map) by Typescript transpiler in NERDTree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Hussein Nazzal, I've managed to solve it this way (because I'm using Angular2 there are a couple of steps to be aware):

- Add an outDir property to tsconfig.json this way:

  ```
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "system",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "removeComments": false,
      "noImplicitAny": false, 
      "outDir": "buildjs/"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
    ]
  }
  ```

- Then in `.vimrc` file add the following:

  ```
  let NERDTreeIgnore=['buildjs$']
  ```
- Don't forget to modify `index.html` and add the following line near `System.import('buildjs/main')`,

  ```
  System.import('app/main')`
  ```
- add to `System.config`

  ```
  map: {
    app: 'buildjs'
  }
  ```

Comment: This is the best answer. I used 'dist' instead of 'buildjs', but this worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Great. I tried fiddling with `System.config` in `index.html` - don't do that :) Change the mapping in `systems.config.js` instead.

Comment: Not a huge fan of this method, you're not hiding autogenerated files, you're simply generating them in a different directory.

Answer (score 2):

to hide files use the `NERDTreeIgnore`

```
let NERDTreeIgnore = ['\.js$' , '\.js.map$']
```

the following line should be used in your `vimrc`file

Comment: the problem is, I don't want to hide javascript files, only the auto generated by typescript.

Comment: this will depend on the method used for transpiling files ... do you use ` --outFile` if you do then you could specify out file to be `somefile.generated.ts` and add '\.generated.ts$' to the ignore list. if you are using gulp you could do similar thing as well .. but there is no other ways to know if the file is a generated file or other wise.but if you output your files in a `dist` directory you might as well hide the dir

Comment: I'm using angular2 configuration, I guess there's have to be a way to configure it using the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: then just specify "outDir" and hide the folder ... or concatenate your files using "outFile" here is a list of ts config options http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

Comment: I think what @WernerEchezuria wants is to hide .js files if a .ts file by the same name (minus the extension) exists in the same directory. At least that's what I would like to figure out how to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you type I (uppercase i) in NERDTree you can toggle the visibility of hidden files.

To hide the files by default put this line in your vimrc:

```
let NERDTreeShowHidden=0
```

Comment: The problem is angular doens't build them with a `.` prefix.